# Can we append DH parameter to certificate file in apache 2.2.29?

Tags: apache, ssl-certificate, httpd.conf

I appended DH parameter to certificate file to use custome 2048 bit DH parameter and restarted HTTPD service, but it is not taking the DH parameter from the certificate in apache version 2.2.29.

current cipher-suite order
SSLCipherSuite EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256+EDH:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA:AES128-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4

please advise on this issue.

Comment: it works on apache 2.2.31

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the httpd documentation, this is supported from 2.2.30 onwards.

Comment: Can you link an example how to append the dh params? I know it must be very easy, because my search engine does not find any.